# Jensen's Integral Inequality in Two Dimensions.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, integral-inequality

There is a similar question on MSE but I don't think this is a duplicate, as my question is not addressed there.

Suppose $\varphi:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ is convex. Then, assuming the integrals exist, it seems reasonable that the following would be true:

$$\int^1_0 \varphi ((f(t),g(t))dt \ge \varphi\left ( \int^1_0 f(t)dt,\int^1_0g(t)dt \right )$$.

Let $\alpha= \int^1_0 f(t)dt$ and $\beta= \int^1_0 g(t)dt.$ Then $h(x,y)=x-\alpha+y-\beta+\varphi (\alpha,\beta)$ is a supporting plane so $\varphi ((f(t),g(t))\ge f(t)-\alpha+g(t)-\beta+\varphi (\alpha,\beta)$ and then integration across the inequality gives the result.

My question is how to show formally that $h$ is indeed a supporting plane. Is it enough to observe that the slope $m_u,$ of the line on the plane through the point $(\alpha, \beta)$ in the direction of a vector $u,$ lies between the left- and right directional derivative, $D\varphi_u((\alpha,\beta)^-)$ and $D\varphi_u((\alpha,\beta)^+); $  that is, $D\varphi_u((\alpha,\beta)^-)\le m_u\le D\varphi_u((\alpha,\beta)^+)?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  the probability measure $\mu$  on $\mathbb R^2$ be the image of Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ induced by the map $t\mapsto (f(t),g(t))$, so $\mu(A)=\lambda(\{t: (f(t),g(t))\in A\}).$  Then the barycenter of $\mu$ is $\left( \int_0^1 f, \int_0^1 g\right)=\int z\, \mu(dz)$ and the ordinary Jensen's inequality gives $$
\int \varphi(z)\,\mu(dz) \ge \varphi\left ( \int z\, \mu(dz)\right).\tag{*}$$
But the left hand side is $\int_0^1\varphi(f(t),g(t))\,dt$, so the desired result holds.

Here by *ordinary Jensen's inequality* I mean the finite dimensional vector version of what the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting) call the "general inequality in a probabilistic setting". Here, one has a probability measure $\mu$ on a finite dimensional vector space $T$ supported in a closed convex set $C\subset T$ for which the vectorial expectation (aka center of gravity or barycenter) $\beta=\int z \mu(dz)$ exists.  One observes that $\beta\in C$, at least when $T$ is finite dimensional. (This is the delicate point in the theory, and requires a Pettis integral formulation in infinite dimensional cases. Clearly $\beta\in H$ for each closed half-space containing $C$, and hence in the intersection of all such $H$.)  If $\varphi$ is convex on $C$, the inequality (*) displayed above holds.  Here *convex* means that for all $x_1, x_2\in C$ and all $t\in[0,1]$, one has $$\varphi(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\le t\varphi(x_1)+(1-t)\varphi(x_2).$$

One way to see this form of Jensen's inequality is to note that the epigraph  $$E_\varphi=\{(x,y):x\in C, y\ge\varphi(x)\}\subset T\times\mathbb R$$ is convex.  To see this, suppose $v_i=(x_i,y_i)\in E_\varphi$, for $i=0,1$, and $t\in[0,1]$.  We have $y_i\ge \phi(x_i)$, so $t y_1+(1-t)y_2\ge t \varphi(x_1) + (1-t)\varphi(x_2)\ge \varphi(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)$ where the first inequality is trivial and the second follows from convexity of $\varphi$. But this already implies  $tv_1+(1-t)v_2 \in E_\varphi,$   verifying the convexity of $E_\varphi.$ Finally, note that (*) follows from  $\gamma=\int_C (z,\varphi(z))\mu(dz)\in E_\varphi$. This last holds because $\gamma$ is the barycenter of the probability measure $\nu$ on $E_\varphi$ that is the image of $\mu$ under the map $z\mapsto (z,\varphi(z))$.

Comment: This is essentially a comment in Hanner's paper $"$On the uniform Convexity of $L^p$  and $l^p"$ which is fine-- and slick, but my question is whether the $same\  proof$ for the one dimensional case, extends to dimension $2$ and hence $n$.

Comment: I think it depends on what your definition of convex function is.  If you define a *convex function* to be a function whose epigraph is a convex set, Jensen's inequality is almost tautologous.  (Or maybe *is* tautologous.) If you define it to be one which is the pointwise limit of functions with nonnegative definite Hessians, or something like that, a certain amount of huffing and puffing is to be expected.  What is your definition, and what is "the same proof for the one dimensional case" you refer to?

Comment: The definition of convexity I am using is $f(tx+(1-t)y\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$. If $X=\mathbb R$ then Jensen's inequality follows from the fact that the slope of any supporting line at $x_0$ lies between $f'(x_0^-)$ and $f'(x_0^+)$. My question is whether the generalization to dimension $2$ and hence $n$ is immediate, passing from supporting lines to supporting planes.

Comment: Using barycenters, you claim that $\int \varphi(z)\,\mu(dz) \ge \varphi\left ( \int z\, \mu(dz)\right)$ follows by the ordinary Jensen Inequality, but $\varphi$ is a function of two variables, not one so the argument seems circular. The integral $\int z \mu(dz)$  is to be understood in the sense of Pettis? As I mentioned, Hanner makes a similar comment in the paper I cited, so I would like to see this explained more fully. Can you provide a careful proof?

Comment: If $\varphi$ is convex, its epigraph, the set of all points $(x,y)$ with $\phi(x)\le y,$  is convex.  The points $(f(t),g(t),\varphi(f(t),g(t)))$ all lie in the epigraph of $\phi$. Hence their barycenter does too.

Comment: My question arose from thinking about Hanner's comment, (which coincides with yours, re: convexity of the epigraph) and wondering if the proof could also be done by a simple extension of the one-dimensional case, replacing supporting lines with supporting planes. Your answer, although it did not address my question, interested me because it seemed like an application of vector-valued integration, of the type Rudin considers briefly in his Functional Analysis book. As far as pretending to be ignorant, I wish that were the case. My ignorance, as you have probably guessed by now, is all too real-

Comment: I have added detail.  Do you know the several books by Rockafellar, Phelps, and Choquet about convexity?  And again: can state exactly what passage in Hanner you are talking about?  Like, page number and equation number?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed, clear answer. The convexity arguments were not a problem, but I was having trouble interpreting the vector-valued integral $\int zd\mu.$ I look at it this way: Let $h(t)=(f(t),g(t))$ and $dt$ be Lebesgue measure. Then, $\int_Ihdt$ denotes the vector $z=(x,y)$ that satisfies $\Lambda z=\int_I(\Lambda h)(t)dt$ for each functional $\Lambda:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ where $(\Lambda h)(t):=\Lambda (h(t)).$ A standard result shows that such a $z$ exists and is unique. Taking $\Lambda =\pi_1,$ we have $x=\int_I f(t)dt$ and similarly $y=\int_I g(t)dt.$ Is this correct?

Comment: Hanner's comment "We shall show below that" .... "is convex. (6) is an immediate consequence of this fact. For the three integrals in (6) are the w-, u-, and v-coordinates of the center of gravity for the distribution of mass given by ..." is on page 241 in ARKIV FOR MATEMATIK Band 3 nr 19, On the uniform convexity of Lp  and lp.

Comment: About $\Lambda$: yes, exactly.  Thanks for the Hanner cite. I will study his paper this weekend.