# Jensen's Inequality : exp$[\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx]$ $\le$ $\int_{0}^1 \exp(f(x))d]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to show that the following equation is true

$$\exp\left(\int_{0}^1 f(x)\,dx\right)\le\int_{0}^1 \exp(f(x))\,dx$$
if $f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$.

I am not sure how to go about showing this. I know that you need to Use Jensen's Inequality and that you should use a Taylor series approximation to show that this true. However I am trouble explaining this (in a proof) showing and explaining the convexity of the function.

Any feed back appreciated.

EDIT:

Lets suppose $$\alpha=\int f(t)dt\space  \text{and} \space  g(x)=m(x-a)+exp(\alpha)$$
Such that the equation supports  at line $\alpha$ Where the equality holds at

$$\int exp(f(t))dt=exp(\alpha)$$

and will allow for:

$$\int exp(f(t)dt-exp(\alpha)=\int exp(f(t))dt-g(\alpha)=\int exp(f(t))dt-g(\int f(t)dt)=\int(exp(f(t))-g(f(t)))dt$$

Since 
Here is my attempt  at the proof of showing when this is true. 
$$exp(f(t)-g(f(t)) \ge0$$

Then the integral is zero only when $exp(f(t))-g(f(t))=0$ almost everywhere this can only happen when $f(t)=\alpha$

Is there any points i should add or clarify ?

Comment: isn't this exactly jensen's inequality? $\exp$ is convex

Comment: Something like this but more complicated was discussed in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2554956/jensens-integral-inequality-in-two-dimensions recently .

Comment: I saw that post but wasn't sure that I could use this as a generalized case ? By using the definition of convexity applying it into the exponential form?

Answer (score 0):

Jensen's inequality tells you that on a probability space $X$, for you this is $[0,1]$ and a probability measure, for you this is the measure corresponding to the linear functional $\int \mathrm dx$, or the Lebesgue measure. Note that 
$$
m([0,1])=1
$$
is satisfied, so this is a probability space.

Take $\phi(x)=e^x$ convex since $\phi''(x)>0$. Then, since $f$ is integrable, Jensen's tells us that 
$$
\exp\left(\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm dx\right)\leq\int_0^1\exp(f(x))\mathrm dx
$$

Comment: Would you need to use a Taylor series approximation to show that statement is true to show that the function is nonnegative at $\phi (x)''$?

Comment: no? you just need to know that $e^x$ is its own derivative and that $e^x$ is strictly positive for any $x$. There are many ways to see the first fact, among which is the series definition (taylor expansion) of $e^x$. But if you are talking about jensen's inequality, I think it's safe to assume basic calculus facts